# Ошибка, при создании Apk в Buildozer (Python kivy)

Tags: android, python, android-sdk, kivy

Пытался, я из кода python kivy сделать apk файл. Установил buildozer и запустил его (buildozer android debug). Но в конце вылезла ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете, пожалуйста, помочь!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В логе написано, что нет файла main.py, поэтому билд не билдится. Может, вы его переименовали или удалили? Именно в нем начинает исполнятся код.